# How do I get a substring from a string

Tags: powershell

I need to retrieve the date substring from the following string:

> DEV_ACID_C179456_2016-11-05_0009_Build

Comment: You should be able to use Regular Expressions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 1):

Quick oneliner:

```
([regex]::Matches("DEV_ACID_C179456_2016-11-05_0009_Build",'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')).value
```

But you need to do your research and share your code as well.

Comment: Then you should upvote the answer.

Comment: @sukanya if autosvets answer solves your problem, consider marking it accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left